# How to setup remote desktop connection permission for systems outside my local network?

Tags: windows-7, networking, remote-desktop

I'm trying to set up my computer so I can remote access it from anywhere including outside the local network.

I have it working locally by following this [tutorial](http://teamtutorials.com/windows-tutorials/windows-remote-desktop-connection) but it was old in XP era. But now I'm using **Windows 7**.

**What I'm doing wrong here? Or am I missing something?**

What I have tried so far:

I know I need to forward the RDP port to 3389 on the router, but I'm not so sure if I'm doing it right. But here is what I did:

1. I went to http://www.dyndns.com/ and get myself a domain name
2. I download the DynDNS updater on my host computer so I can use the DNS rather than my IP address (I can ping my newly registered xxxx.selfip.com so I assuming I got that right)
3. I went to my router admin page setup the port forwarding table to 3389 with my private IP address like this:

   [image: D-Link Air G Plus Advanced options screen]

All the remote desktop services are running and it works fine in my local network

But I when I try to connect I get the error:

[image: Remote Desktop Errors]

Comment: Does it work if you enter your internet IP address?
Is the IP address on the target computer reserved/static?

Comment: it works when I enter my local private IP address, I got 2 PC here, so when I enter 192.168.0.102 from the other PC it works. But when I try to use xxxx.selfip.net it doesn't work :(

Comment: the IP is dynamic at the moment, not static or reserved

Comment: From outside your LAN, have you tried to connect using your internet IP address?  The issue may be with the dyndns service.

Comment: @firedfly from outside using my neighbor's Wif I can ping to xxx.selfip.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the remote desktop is working internally, the problem must be between the computer and router.

First I would test the port is open using [Can You See Me](http://www.canyouseeme.org/) or [telnet](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q187628).  If you receive no response, then have a look at the routers firewall settings, it maybe blocking the incoming connection.

One other possibility is your ISP maybe blocking port 3389.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use the xxxx.selfip.net from the LAN side of the router, many routers can't resolve the WAN Side of the router from inside the LAN.  It's like picking up the phone and dialing your own phone number.  Try using a friend or family members computer to remote connect and see if it works from outside.

Comment: I tried that using my neighbor's Wifi

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the firewall on the Windows 7 computer to make sure it allows remote connections from the internet.  On my computer I have three profiles for connections when setting up the firewall: *Domain*, *Private* and *Public*.  If the port is not open for the Public profile, that may explain the issue.

Comment: Yes I enabled them both Private and Public in the Windows Firewall